# How to make a list `global` in c#?

Tags: c#

Firstly, most of my experience with coding is through python hence my use of `global`

I have a list and I want to be able to search the list and find all words that are of `x` length. My main issue is not knowing how to call a function from inside an event listener.

So `myList` is generated inside of my function `functionOne`, I am then wanting to use this list inside `functionTwo` and then finally I want to call it when `buttonOne` is clicked. E.g `buttonOne_Click ....`

This is what I have so far for `functionOne`

```
public List<string> noDup(List<string> myList)
        {
            var convert = myList.ConvertAll(i => i.ToLower());
            List<string> remove = convertLower.Distinct().ToList();
            return remove;
        }
```

`functionTwo`

```
    public List<string> length(List<string> myList)
    {
        int i = int.Parse(lengthSearch.Text);
        List<string> temp = new List<string>();

        foreach(string item in myList)
        {
            if(item.Length == i)
            {
                temp.Add(item);
            }
        }
        searchResult.Text = string.Join(",", temp);
    }
```

And finally my event listener

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            length(remove);
        }
```

NOTE: `remove` is the list I am trying to work with

But there is no output with this code because I get an error saying remove doesn't exist in this context, I'm unsure how I make this list `global`

Comment: Create a Public Method which returns the list that you want to work with then call the method to generate the list whenever you need it.

Comment: This is a language fundamental  concept. Follow some tutorials first before trying to write Python style code in C#.

Comment: 'follow some tutorials' really? is that all you can do to help? i would prefer if you just didnt comment anything if that is your input.

Comment: Define it outside a method : List<string> myList = null;
public void functionOne()
{
   myList = new myList() { "a","b","c"};
}

Comment: Well, Aphelion isn't wrong about you needing to do some tutorials. If this question is any indication, you are missing two concepts from your understanding of C# that knowing would immediately give you the answer to this question. First, there's no such thing as "global variables" in C#, and the closest you can get is by having a static field in a public class. Second, to make an object accessible from outside a method, you need to _declare_ it outside of that method (e.g. as a class field).

Answer (score 0):

We'll here's the general idea how to achieve this in a win forms c# application.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private List<string> _remove;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            length(_remove);
        }

        public List<string> noDup(List<string> myList)
        {
            var convert = myList.ConvertAll(i => i.ToLower());
            _remove = convertLower.Distinct().ToList();

        }

        public List<string> length(List<string> myList)
        {
            int i = int.Parse(lengthSearch.Text);
            List<string> temp = new List<string>();

            foreach (string item in myList)
            {
                if (item.Length == i)
                {
                    temp.Add(item);
                }
            }
            searchResult.Text = string.Join(",", temp);
        }
    }
}
```

Mind this doesn't build since I just used your code. For example the `length` method should return a `List<string>` but it doesn't. You would probably want to change the list that's passed in and then return it, or mutate the class level variable `_remove`.

Either way the event handler `button1_Click` needs to work with a class level variable (such as `_remove` that I added) or call a method that will return the list (as is present in the other [anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43961986/2546433) by Zbigniew.)

Comment: Also, this isn't what I would consider 'best practice', but you probably just want to get something working - and that's fine. When you get a feel for it, I definitely recommend looking at some documentation (maybe on the MVP pattern model - view- presenter). Maybe even another UI technology - WPF which has a different, more modern approach and  predominatly uses the MVVM pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Put all the functions in the same class and use noDup on your list instance.

```
    public List<string> noDup(List<string> myList)
        {
            var convert = myList.ConvertAll(i => i.ToLower());
            List<string> remove = convertLower.Distinct().ToList();
            return remove;
        }

    public void length(List<string> myList)
    {
        int i = int.Parse(lengthSearch.Text);
        List<string> temp = new List<string>();

        foreach(string item in myList)
        {
            if(item.Length == i)
            {
                temp.Add(item);
            }
        }
        searchResult.Text = string.Join(",", temp);
    }

        private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   
            var remove = noDup(yourInputList);
            length(remove);
        }
```